# Cannot find symbol return DaggerApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.builder()

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I switched to Hilt dependency injection this morning. After everything is done, then I stuck with this one:

> error: cannot find symbol
> return DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.builder()
> ^   symbol: variable DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC

I did try to find the solution my self and I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742988/error-cannot-find-symbol-return-daggerapplication-hiltcomponents-singletonc-bui), but I already added all module's build.gradle
Please take a look at mine if I did anything wrong.

My application:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : MultiDexApplication()
```

Project Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.34-beta'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

App Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.34-beta'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.34-beta'
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01'
```

[image]
Thank you all

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my case this error caused by `androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel` dependency

According to Dagger Hilt Github comments:

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler"
```

should be removed.

see [this](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2541), also [this](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2541)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually find out the problem. It was because I used @GlideModule wrongly:

```
@GlideModule
class Glide4Engine @Inject constructor(
   private val context:Context
): AppGlideModule() {
}
```

So, I have to do it another way like this:

```
@GlideModule
class Glide4Engine : AppGlideModule() {
    // Empty
}
```

And create other class:

```
class MyGlide @Inject constructor(
    private val context: Context
) {
  //// Things
}
```

Hoping it can help if you are facing a problem like that ;)